# Multiple boxes with many rows on a line with wrapping when overflowing

Tags: boxes, tex4ht

I would like to have multiple boxes with many rows on a line with wrapping when the boxes are overflowing.

The idea would be to build a custom contributors/reviewers environment that I can also use with TeX4ht:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\ccReviewer}[1]{%
    \hbox{#1}
}
\newcommand{\ccAffiliation}[1]{%
    \hbox{#1}
}
\newcommand{\ccReviewersList}[1]{%
    \hbox{%
        \foreach \reviewer / \affiliation in #1{%
            \vbox{
                \ccReviewer{\reviewer}%
                \ccAffiliation{\affiliation}
            }
        }
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    {\large Contributors and Reviewers}\\
    \vspace{5mm}
    \def\ccReviewers{%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation%
    }
    \ccReviewersList{\ccReviewers}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Here is the current output:

[image: CCRA]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{pgffor,stackengine}

\newcommand{\ccReviewer}[1]{%
    \hbox{#1}
}
\newcommand{\ccAffiliation}[1]{%
    \hbox{#1}
}
\newcommand{\ccReviewersList}[1]{%
        \foreach \reviewer / \affiliation in #1{%
            \Longstack[l]{%
                \ccReviewer{\reviewer}
                \ccAffiliation{\affiliation}
            }
        }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    {\large Contributors and Reviewers}\\
    \vspace{5mm}
    \def\ccReviewers{%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation%
    }
    \ccReviewersList{\ccReviewers}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could streamline it further:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{pgffor,stackengine}

\newcommand{\ccReviewersList}[1]{%
    \foreach \reviewer / \affiliation in #1{%
        \addstackgap[4pt]{\Longstack[l]{\reviewer{} \affiliation}}\hspace{4pt} 
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    {\large Contributors and Reviewers}\\
    \vspace{5mm}
    \def\ccReviewers{%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation,%
        Author/Affiliation%
    }
    \ccReviewersList{\ccReviewers}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

...or even replace `pgffor` with `listofitems`, as such, allowing you to not require the `%` trailers in the `\ccReviewers` list:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{stackengine,listofitems}

\newcommand{\ccReviewersList}[1]{%
    \setsepchar[?]{,?/}%
    \readlist*\authlist{#1}%
    \foreachitem\x\in\authlist[]{%
        \addstackgap[4pt]{%
        \Longstack[l]{\authlist[\xcnt,1] \authlist[\xcnt,2]}}\hspace{4pt}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    {\large Contributors and Reviewers}\\
    \vspace{5mm}
    \def\ccReviewers{
        Author/Affiliation,
        Author/Affiliation,
        Author/Affiliation,
        Author/Affiliation,
        Author/Affiliation,
        Author/Affiliation,
        Author/Affiliation,
        Author/Affiliation,
        Author/Affiliation,
        Author/Affiliation,
        Author/Affiliation
    }
    \ccReviewersList{\ccReviewers}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!